# What does "taking operands immediately following the opcode" mean?

Tags: java, jvm, stack

I am reading the book [Inside the Java 2 Virtual Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071350934) and I can't understand what this means:

> The Java Virtual Machine is stack-based rather than register-based
>   because its instructions take their operands from the operand stack
>   rather than from registers. Instructions can also take operands from
>   other places, such as immediately following the opcode (the byte
>   representing the instruction) in the bytecode stream, or from the
>   constant pool.

Can anyone help me with the part:

> Instructions can also take operands from other places, such as
>   immediately following the opcode

, perhaps with an example?

Comment: This is very common in assembly.  E.g. A single byte opcode with a double byte operand will take totally three bytes of byte codes in the class file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, there's an iinc instruction which adds a constant value to the local variable like this:

```
iinc 1, 8
```

This means "add 8 to the local variable #1". The constant 8 is directly written in the bytecode, following the iinc instruction code and constant 1: `0x84 0x01 0x08`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fancy way of saying that data values can be embedded within the byte code itself.

Consider `sipush` instruction for an example. It pushes a `short` value onto the stack. The value of the `short` comes from two bytes that follow the instruction:

```
sipush <byte1> <byte2>
```

Another situation that the paragraph fails to mention is when the value is embedded within the opcode itself, as in `iconst_<N>` instructions. For example,

```
iconst_5
```

loads constant `5` onto the stack. The value of `5` does not come from a separate storage, because it is embedded in the meaning of the instruction opcode.